# What is Steam's OpenID URL

Tags: support, openid

I was wondering that there is a login in Steam option here and was wondering what is the URL for it on any site that has OpenID support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just checked, it appears to be http://steamcommunity.com/openid

When you click the login "buttons" on a Stack Exchange site, the manual textbox updates with the OpenID URL of the provider you've selected.

Navigating directly to that URL doesn't do anything helpful, but using that as the OpenID provider does, and presents a Steam login page.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55878/stack-overflow-and-steam-community-openids

Short: it's broken.

Comment: @Bora It _was_ broken, it works now.

Comment: @bora It worked for me when I tested it?

Comment: My bad. It's indeed working. I should've checked on this once more. Last time I needed to implement OpenID, the site gave me so much headache that I responded negatively a bit too early.